# Reading 6 bytes from filebuffer

Tags: c++, ifstream

Guys, i need to read 6 bytes from filebuffer and store them as unsigned number.

```
ifstream ifs("dummy.txt", ios::binary);
unsigned __int64 result = 0;
ifs.read((char*)&result, 6);
```

This is correct?

Comment: yep - it compiles and works, butt i cannot be sure that i get correct value;(

Comment: unsigned __int64 is 8 bytes, so the idea is to give enough space for read method

Comment: For any piece of code you write you are always going to need some way of *testing* it. E.g. write a test harness, single step through the code, inspect values in a debugger, i.e. do whatever it takes to prove to yourself that your code works as intended - don't just assume that it *should work*. What is in the first 6 bytes of the file dummy.txt ? What value did you get in `result` ?

Comment: thanks a lot, but i have no idea how to check it - if i had - i wouldn't be asking it - i know how to use debugger

Comment: (1) Look at the contents of "results.txt"; (2) look at the value of `result` in a debugger; (3) if (1) == (2) then it probably works. For more thorough testing repeat (1)..(3) with different contents in "results.txt"

Comment: yep - i'm doing this way.. - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the standard type of a 64 bit unsigned integer is either
'unsigned long long' or 'uint64_t'.  And second, you have to know the
format of the data in the file you're reading.  I've never seen a format
which uses six bytes, so it's difficult to guess, but supposing it's
binary, you should use either:

```
uint64_t readSix( std::istream& src )
{
    uint64_t result = checkedGet( src ) ;
    result |= checkedGet( src ) <<  8;
    result |= checkedGet( src ) << 16;
    result |= checkedGet( src ) << 24;
    result |= checkedGet( src ) << 32;
    result |= checkedGet( src ) << 48;
    return result;
}
```

or

```
uint64_t readSix( std::istream& src )
{
    uint64_t result = checkedGet( src ) << 48;
    result |= checkedGet( src ) << 32;
    result |= checkedGet( src ) << 24;
    result |= checkedGet( src ) << 16;
    result |= checkedGet( src ) <<  8;
    result |= checkedGet( src );
    return result;
}
```

depending on the format, with:

```
unsigned char checkedGet( std::istream& src )
{
    int result = src.get();
    if ( result == EOF )
        throw UnexpectedEof();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Or use something clever as protobuf http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/ because it handles endianess and efficient encoding.

Comment: Compiler writes that offset is too high for result |= checkedGet( stream ) << 32;

Comment: @madeinsoviets Ouch.  Yes: the expression `checkedGet( stream ) << 32` is processed first, as unsigned int, and if unsigned int has 32 bits or less, it's formally undefined behavior (but a good compiler will at least warn in the case of a constant).  The simplest solution is to change the return type of checkedGet to uint64_t; otherwise, casting the results to uint64_t before shifting will do the trick as well (if, say, checkedGet is used elsewhere, where uint64_t wouldn't be appropriate).